# Rewrite code using the magrittr compound assignment pipe-operator %<>%

Tags: r

How would I rewrite the below code using `%<>%` ?

The new value of `cemetaries` will be the result of...

```
cemetaries <-
```

Start with cemetaries, AND THEN...

```
  cemetaries %>%
```

SELECT 3 COLUMNS, THEN EVERTHING ELSE, AND THEN...

```
 select(LEGAL, OWNER, PROJECT, everything())
```

Comment: Replace `%>%` with `%<>%` i.e `cemetaries %<>% select(LEGAL, OWNER, PROJECT, everything())`

Comment: Why would one use `%<>%` if `%>%` achieves the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the pipe operator (`%>%`) with `%<>%`.

```
cemetaries %<>% select(LEGAL, OWNER, PROJECT, everything())
```

The benefit of using `%<>%` is that it by default updates the lhs object so that you don't have to do `cemetaries <-` .

When you use pipe operator to save the changed object back you need to do :

```
cemetaries <- cemetaries %>% select(LEGAL, OWNER, PROJECT, everything())
```

`cemetaries <-` part can be avoided if you use `%<>%`.